# How to get real path from FileProvider URI?

Tags: java, android, uri

I have this code for decoding `content://` URI:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
                     new String[] { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA },
                     null, null, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(columnIndex);

} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {cursor.close()};
}
```

but it doesn't work for `FileProvider` URI (e.g Chrome Dev URI of downloaded files: `content://com.chrome.dev.FileProvider/downloads/`). Is there a way to get a real path?

Comment: what do you need real path for?

Comment: Ability to copy to a new path or delete file.

Comment: then see `ContentResolver#openInputStream` and `ContentResolver#delete`

Comment: Yes, it's possible, thanks.

Comment: Check this may help you: https://thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=12045

Comment: no @shweta it will not help

Comment: @pskink Deleting doesn't work for Chrome URI: permission denied. MediaStore URI deleted without problems.

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: @pskink Nothing, only `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing org.chromium.chrome.browser.util.ChromeFileProvider uri content://com.chrome.dev.FileProvider/downloads/%5BTorrent-Soft.Net%5D_KEYS.torrent from pid=2406, uid=10063 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`. Even if I request rights with `grantUriPermission()` it gives an error that the rights cannot be granted.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink `activity.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);`

Comment: and permission request: `activity.grantUriPermission(activity.getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); int takeFlags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION; activity.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);`

Comment: you cannot `grantUriPermission` for yourself - it has to be done by a package that owns `com.chrome.dev.FileProvider` - imagine you have a folder with read only files and anybody can read it but only trusted people can change them - it is obvious that it is your responiblity to `grantChangePermission` for them

Comment: I cannot delete file until the content provider allows it to be deleted?

Comment: dont you think it makes sense? would it be better if anybody could delete anything? what would be any permissions for then?

Comment: @pskink Yes, but situation arises that user of my app choose option to delete file after opening, but it can be deleted only if the path to the file is available, otherwise the file cannot be deleted. This behavior is very strange for user.

Comment: @proninyaroslav Did you find any solution to get the FilePath from Chrome URI, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution for get real path from file provider URI.

First you need to define file provider path file as following.

> provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Declare file provider in **AndroidMenifest.xml** as following.

> AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<application>
    .
    .
    .
    <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
 </application>
```

Now in activity side.

> MyActivity.java

```
private Uri picUri;

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (Utils.isNougat()) {
            picUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), imageHelper
                    .createImageFile());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }else {
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(imageHelper.createImageFile());
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Const.ServiceCode.TAKE_PHOTO);
    }


    /**
     * This method is used for handel result after captured image from camera .
    */
    private void onCaptureImageResult() {
        if(Utils.isNougat()){
            documentImage = imageHelper.getRealPathFromURI(picUri.getPath());
        }else {
            documentImage = imageHelper.getRealPathFromURI(picUri);
        }
    }
```

Following my method for get real path.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null,
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file
            // path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            try {
                int idx = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AppLog.handleException(ImageHelper.class.getName(), e);
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.error_get_image), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                result = "";
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope you solve your problem.

Comment: and where is your overloaded method `public String getRealPathFromURI(String contentUriPath)` ?

Comment: doing so I'm getting idx = -1. The URI string in debugger looks good with provider virtual directory and all in place

Comment: I'm getting the following Error: `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested column: -1, # of columns: 2`. At the line `result = cursor.getString(idx);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@TargetApi(19)
 private static String generatePath(Uri uri,Context context){
    String filePath = null;
    if(DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)){
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
        String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);



        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for getting full path from selected file.
Meybe it will help You

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/zip");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // file browser has been found on the device
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File Browser"), SELECT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);





@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE) {

                final Uri uri = data.getData();

                if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
                    // the direct path to the file has been returned
                    final String path = uri.getPath();
                    final File file = new File(path);
                    mFilePath = path;

                    updateFileInfo(file.getName(), file.length(), mFileType);
                } else if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
                    // an Uri has been returned
                    mFileStreamUri = uri;

                    final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM))
                        mFileStreamUri = extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);

                    // file name and size must be obtained from Content Provider
                    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_URI, uri);
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(SELECT_FILE_REQ, bundle, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        final Uri uri = args.getParcelable(EXTRA_URI);

        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if (data != null && data.moveToNext()) {
            /*
             * Here we have to check the column indexes by name as we have requested for all. The order may be different.
             */
            final String fileName = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)/* 0 DISPLAY_NAME */);
            final int fileSize = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE) /* 1 SIZE */);
            String filePath = null;
            final int dataIndex = data.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            if (dataIndex != -1)
                filePath = data.getString(dataIndex /* 2 DATA */);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath))
                mFilePath = filePath;

            updateFileInfo(fileName, fileSize, mFileType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. getting real path from URI

```
File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));
```

method

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { //checking
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA); 
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following Error: `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested column: -1, # of columns: 2`. At the line `result = cursor.getString(idx);`